# How can we use previously stored symbolic expression in the dsolve command without cut and paste

Tags: matlab

Hallo,friends
we have the following problem

```
syms t u0 u1

u0=sin(t);

R1= diff(u0,'t',2)+u0-u0^3;

u1=dsolve('D2u1+u1=R1','t')

gives the ans
u1=R1+c1*sin(t)+c2*cos(t).
```

But it does not use the value of R1.
How can we do this.Please,tell me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What has this got to do with linux-kernel? I am guessing this has got something to do with mathematica and have tagged it as such.

Comment: What programming language is this? It's certainly not mathematica.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's Maple. I've changed the tag to reflect my guess.

Comment: This is actually MATLAB using the Symbolic Toolbox.

Comment: This is the third matlab type question this user has posted that has been mis-tagged.

@Anant: please take more care with your tagging, members of the SO community tend to only follow tags they are interested in (and can therefore help with).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for inconvenience.
I got answer to my question:

syms t u0 u1

u0=sin(t);

R1= diff(u0,'t',2)+u0-u0^3;

eq1=strcat('D2u1+u1=',char(R1));

u1=dsolve(eq1,'t')

will return the answer using the value of R1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use subs(u1, 'R1', R1) to perform the substitution.

Comment: +1: This is correct, but an even simpler way is to do `subs(u1)`, which replaces as many variables in `u1` as it can with other symbolic values/equations from the workspace.